# How to get from private key and seed phrase to account address?

Tags: hash, blockchain, ethereum, metamask

This info are of a metamask dummy account. Does anyone know the process to get the hash_mm from seed and/or private_key?

```
    seed        = "else wrist ..."
    private_key = 'd75d1...'
    hash_mm     = '0x0411CAb45688e0815B8c36813d148E1E43dDa868'
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11272/97038

```js
const secp256k1 = require('secp256k1');
const pubKey = secp256k1.publicKeyCreate(private_key, false).slice(1);
```